# Making sense of「どこか、吉田さんはそういう交際経験とかその先の経験とか...なんだか、勝手に無いように思ってしまってた」

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

The below line came from the recent chapter of hige wo soru manga. Yoshida told Sayu about how he met his ex girlfriend who suddenly joined his workplace. His ex was his high school sempai. Sayu had a monologue that went like this

> そう、そうだ、吉田さんに昔恋人がいたなんて自然なことだ
>
> こんなに誠実な人なんだし
>
> でもそうは思っていても、**どこか、吉田さんはそういう交際経験とかその先の経験とか...なんだか、勝手に無いように思ってしまってた**

I can't grasp the overall meaning of the bold part. How to understand the「どこか...とか...とか...なんだ」structure? What does 勝手に無いように mean? If possible, I'd appreciate a literal English rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どこか, なんだか, and 勝手に all modify 思ってしまってた as adverbs and describe how the speaker (Sayu) was thinking what she was thinking. どこか means “somewhere”, but it could be understood as “somewhere in her mind” in this context.

そういう交際経験とかその先の経験とか is the subject of 無い. Sayu was somehow thinking Yoshida didn’t have such experiences.

Comment: Thanks! Just to confirm, 先の経験 can be understood as "previous experiences," not "future experiences" right?

Comment: @RaySiplao: No, `その先` is like “beyond that”. `その先の経験` refers to experiences that follow `交際経験`. It implies sexual relationships.